# When editing a form in ActiveAdmin, can you override the Update action to Create instead of Update?

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I would like an AdminUser to be able to edit a Survey and then upon saving the edits, a new Survey object be created instead of the current Survey being edited.

Tried to override the update action in the controller to call the create action instead of update, but no luck. Here's one of the attempts (I know you can't just call create like that, but it shows the intent!):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Survey do
  ...

  controller do
    def update
      survey_hash = (params[:survey].to_h) 
      create(options = survey_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

How would I be able to achieve this? Thanks!!

Update: The requested Survey model:

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :admin_user
  has_many :sections
  has_many :submissions
  has_many :question_sets, through: :sections
  has_many :questions, through: :question_sets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sections, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end
```

Comment: Could you post how did you model your problem? (your models).

Comment: Calling `to_h` on params seems odd unless that's an array of values you need to convert. Otherwise it should already be a hash. Additionally, assigning variables in method calls seems strange for Ruby, though if you use Python that could be an old habit brought over.

Comment: Sure. Editing now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Survey do
  controller do
    def your_method_name
      @survey = Survey.new(survey_params) 
      if @survey.save
        # ...
      else
        # ...
      end
    end

    def survey_params
      params.permit(:survey => [:param1, :param2]) # remove id parameter to make it work
    end
  end
end
```

I found in this link: [Active Admin](https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html) informations about update the controller.

- You have to remove the `id` parameter, otherwise `Survey.new` won't work if it finds an id parameter (it will try to update instead of saving).

P.s: It doesn't seem correct to create a new survey for each update. I think you should have a has_many relation between a survey and its updates.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to clone the Survey use a custom action like so:

```
action_item(:copy_and_edit, only: :show) do
  link_to "Clone and edit", duplicate_survey_path(resource), :method => :get
end

member_action :duplicate, method: :get do
  @survey = resource.dup
  render :new, layout: false
end
```

If your intent is to maintain a history consider an [auditing plugin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

#### Another solution

1. Override the `new` controller method:

   ```
   def new
     @survey = Survery.find(params[:clone_id]) if params[:clone_id]
     super
   end
   ```
2. Place a link wherever you want to drive the "Clone" action from:

Resource show page:

```
    action_item :duplicate, only: :show do
      link_to 'Clone', new_survey_path(clone_id: resource.id), method: :get
    end
```

Resource edit form:

```
      f.actions do
        f.action :submit
        f.action :cancel, label: 'Clone',
                          url: new_survey_path(clone_id: resource.id)
      end
```